# ConTeXt: Style only the first body row of all xtables in a document

Tags: context, border, body, extreme-tables

## Background

A generated document contains tables with and without headers. For the tables with headers there is no issue, as exemplified by:

[image: Header row]

## Problem

The generated document does not include a horizontal line for the table when there is no header:

[image: No header row]

The desired output has a border before the table body begins:

[image: Desired header row]

## Code

The generated table code:

```
\startplacetable[location=none]
\startxtable
\startxtablebody[body]
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=right,width={0.50\textwidth}] {\bf ID} \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=right,width={0.50\textwidth}] FSA-1 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtable
\stopplacetable
```

The styling code:

```
\setupxtable[
  frame=off,
  option={stretch,width},
  split=yes,
  header=repeat,
]
\setupxtable[head][topframe=on,bottomframe=on]
\setupxtable[foot][bottomframe=on]
```

Adding code to style just the body causes all lines to have a border. For example:

```
\setupxtable[body][topframe=on,bottomframe=off]
```

Produces:

[image: Table with body style]

And the following error message appears:

```
setup           > error in line 8, namespace 'xtable', key 'body'
```

## Question

How can the first row, and only the first row, of an xtable body be styled to have a border (such that the desired output is produced)?

Note that the bottom border for the header row will have to be disabled to avoid doubling up the line. Also note that since the code is generated, it is not feasible to modify each xtable instance. Ideally, the border can be added using [`setupxtable`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/xtables). The documentation is lacking in this area.

## Environment

- ConTeXt MKIV 2018.01.04 17:37

Comment: My ConTeXt version does not compile xtable but I would give a try to `\startxrow[topframe=on,bottomframe=on]`. Sorry I can't check this.

Comment: Not possible, see this thread: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/090527.html

Comment: BTW, those “errors” are there because you are not using the pandoc preamble.  Simply add `\setupxtable[head,body,foot][]` to your document to make them disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automated high-level way to do this, as already discussed on the ConTeXt mailing list (https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/090527.html).  You can however, hack your way into the `\startxrow` macro and branch on the first row (index 0).

The table in your question is incomplete and I doubt that it was generate like this by pandoc.  The resulting document does not typeset.  I have completed the table with some bogus content.

```
\unprotect

\unexpanded\def\startxrow
  {\begingroup
   \ifnum\currentxtablerow=0
     \setupcurrentxtable[topframe=on]
   \fi
   \doifelsenextoptionalcs\tabl_x_start_row_yes\tabl_x_start_row_nop}

\protect

\setupxtable[
  frame=off,
  option={stretch,width},
  split=yes,
  header=repeat,
]
\setupxtable[head][topframe=on,bottomframe=on]
\setupxtable[body][]
\setupxtable[foot][bottomframe=on]

\starttext

\startplacetable[location=none]
  \startxtable
    \startxtablebody[body]
      \startxrow
        \startxcell[align=right,width={0.50\textwidth}] {\bf ID} \stopxcell
        \startxcell[align=right,width={0.50\textwidth}] FSA-1 \stopxcell
      \stopxrow
    \stopxtablebody
    \startxtablefoot[foot]
      \startxrow
        \startxcell[align=right,width={0.50\textwidth}] Description \stopxcell
        \startxcell[align=right,width={0.50\textwidth}] ??? \stopxcell
      \stopxrow
    \stopxtablefoot
  \stopxtable
\stopplacetable

\stoptext
```

[image]